# Meaning of "to get through to something"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Take a look at this:

> "After a year, the research participants had an angiogram—a special X-ray that shows the trickle of blood that **gets through to** the heart—and the results were compared to ..."

The author is talking about the arteries *inside* the heart; because the subject matter is heart disease. So shouldn't it just say:

> "the trickle of blood that ***gets through** the heart"?

I don't get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, an angiogram shows up the blood vessels which supply the heart muscle, so the reference is to blood *getting through to* the heart to keep it working, not to the blood being pumped by the heart.

Answer (score 2):

[***To get through to***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/get_through_to.html) means to reach, to get to, to have contact with.

So your sentence means

> a special X-ray that shows the trickle of blood that *makes its way through* to the heart (until it reaches the heart)

You can find some thesaurus synonyms [here](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/get_through_to/synonyms).